# Linq2Couchbase joins on List<> to id

Tags: c#, linq, couchbase, sql++

I have two objects

```
public class Card : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string BackgroundColour { get; set; }
    public string Texture { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> Category { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Category : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Parent { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is, using the Couchbase SDK, join these two objects together (Card.Category => Category.Id) in one database hit (Like a classic SQL Stored Procedure that brings me back all the data to populate both objects), but all of the ([examples](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Linq2Couchbase/blob/master/docs/joins.md) I found have it from id => id rather than a List of Ids (Many) to (one) id.

An example of something I tried to do...

```
var query = from card in context.Query<Card>()
            from categoryId in card.Category.Ids
            join category in context.Query<Category>()
            on categoryId equals category.Id
            select new CardView { Id = card.Id, Categories = category};
```

Comment: Have you tried `(c => c.Category.Contains(Category.Id))`

Comment: can you give me a full example?

Comment: please show your linq query.

Comment: I don't have one yet as none of them work

Comment: if we are to help you - it helps to know exactly what you tried. please read [mcve]

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: Try following : var query = (from card in context.Card
            join category in context.Category
            on card.Id equals category.Id
            select new { card = card, categories = category}).ToList();

Comment: This is something which is ok to do if there is one id in one object and another id in another object, however I have a list of Id's in one object